# What is an elegent way to use tab in a text area with two way data binding in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm experimenting with a text editor (just playing around with different ways to make one) and am using a svelte text area. One problem with this text area is that tab is not enabled by default. I was able to implement Ctrl+s quite easily but tab is more tricky.

The current method I'm using is to:

1. Prevent default when there is a keydown on tab
2. Set variables for the current cursor position, and a flag to indicate tab was pressed
3. Manipulate the text area text using the substring method for strings to substring up to the selected area and after the selected area
4. On subsequent keydown or keyup to reset my tab flag

This feels quite hacky to me so wanted to see if there was a more efficient way to do this.

Posting code here:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    const endpoint = "http://localhost:5000/";

    // State
    let planner_text;
    let textarea_elem;

    let tab_selected = 0;
    let tab = false;

    // Load test.txt on mount
    onMount(async () => {
        const response = await fetch(endpoint);
        const data = await response.json();
        planner_text = data["text"];
    });

    // Save functionality
    const update_planner = () => {
        fetch(endpoint, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: planner_text
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        });
    }

    // Key down funcitonality
    const keydown = e => {
        tabset();

        // save
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 83) {
            e.preventDefault();
            update_planner();
        } /* tab */ else if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const {selectionStart, selectionEnd} = textarea_elem;

            tab_selected = selectionStart + 1;
            tab = true;

            planner_text = planner_text.substring(0, selectionStart) 
                + '\t' + planner_text.substring(selectionEnd)

            textarea_elem.setSelectionRange(tab_selected, tab_selected)
        }
    }

    const tabset = () => {
        if (tab) {
            textarea_elem.setSelectionRange(tab_selected, tab_selected)
            tab = false;
        }
    };
</script>

<main>
    <div class="container">
        <textarea
            class="scratch-pad"
            bind:this={textarea_elem}
            bind:value={planner_text}
            on:keydown={keydown}
            on:keyup={() => {tabset()}}/>
        <button class="lock-in-btn" on:click={update_planner}>Lock in</button>
    </div>
</main>
```